# Can I get access to another app's files in Android?

Tags: android, file, android-fileprovider

I have 2 apps. [App1] has some files in internal storage . [App2] need access to these files from [App1].
How to make it?

In the past it was possible to give same userId to these apps. So, they would share same linux user environment. But it was deprecated in api 29.

Of course, I can use some providers and require needed files from [App2]. It will open file picker where I can choose required file.

But I don't need that user would care about choosing this file. I'd like to retrieve this file without any UI actions.

It's would be greate, were there a possibility to create some directory that could be shared between several apps. Is there smth. like that?

(May be there's any possibility to encrypt some folder in external storage using some lib?)

Comment: "[App1] has some files in internal storage . [App2] need access to these files from [App1]" -- have App1 expose some API that App2 uses, such as a `ContentProvider` or a bound remote `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use SAF and hence a user interaction to let the user choose a file from another app if this file is on public external storage.

You can also add your own file provider to app1.

App2 can then request files from app1 without user interaction.

Using a provider app1 could keep its files in private storage.

Hmmm.. I'm not sure anymore if this still goes without a read permission given from provider..